# How long varchar needed in sql server to save base64String from C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, base64

I'm save my image to my SQLServer Database with string data type after convert it to base64string in C#. Now i want to load it back, but it can't loaded after i convert it back to image?

Any Solution?

Comment: Using a `varbinary()` data type and parameters would allow you to avoid doing any conversions to/from Base 64 and just work with `byte[]` in your C# code. Surely better than treating everything as a string.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - potentially true, but it would create some work to do, probably making a SQLparameter in c# and attaching it to his command - he can't just go and change the column type to varbinary and cancel the Convert.ToBase64 part - then he also has to change his stored procedure probably

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could save your base64 string as varchar(MAX) - what I would do with your code if this does not help is

1) ensure you are getting the same length of data back that you save

2) Ensure your code for converting image to BASE64 string, then back to image from string works (without the DB in the middle)

Comment: i already try this before, but still not work @Andrew

Comment: what happens if you try making your BASE64 string, then with that string, immediately perform the process of changing the string back into an image? It could be the data is going to the database and back ok, but your image processing is wrong - you need to rule that out. If you can proves the image processing all works ok, then it is a question of checking what data is going to the DB, and what data is coming back

Comment: i already trace the error when i retrieve it back from database when

Comment: Image img = Image.FromStream(ms,true)

Comment: I found that the principle of the code does work - is it possible for you to record the value of the string you send to the database, then find out how it is different when you load it up again?  Does it get truncated, or has the data changed?  Record things like the length of the string you save, then what comes back

Comment: for example, is the BASE64 definitely going into the correct DB field?  You could possibly be sending it to the wrong field when you build a SQL string for example.

Comment: i found it different when i retrieved it back from database, Thanks sir for this help i got it.. But what data type in sqlserver that can handle more than 78784 of length ? is varchar(MAX) can handle it?

Comment: varchar(MAX) should handle up to  2billion+ bytes  - what data type does your stored procedure have?  Is it truncating data?  If data is coming back different, I would guess here it did not go in right - check length of data in db

Comment: thanks sir it really helpful me, it's my parameter that i set only varchar(100). It supposed to be varchar(MAX). Thank's a lot

Comment: @Student - I'm glad it helped